# Automated performance test for web application

Tags: performance, testing

I'm currently developing a webapp with JBoss Seam, the webapp uses EJB to connect to the backend layer (J2EE + Oracle).

We are planning to use Selenium to create the functional tests, but I'd also like to have some automated performance tests for the client layer. Would it be possible to use Selenium for this or is it a bad idea?

I know tools like YSlow, PageSpeed or Firebug can be used for measuring the web performance, but is there anyway to automate this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using selenium for performance test is a very bad idea as it is painfully slow.

For simple tests, try apache bench (ab), for more complex tests (e.g.: one requiring user login, verification of returned pages, detailed statistics) use JMeter.

In my experience JMeter can be a bit slow, if your system really performs well you might have to use JMeter's distributed mode which uses multiple (synchronized) JMeter clients.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Apache JMeter for Web Performance Tests:

http://jmeter.apache.org/

You can put together your test plans with a lot of different components.

There is also the feature to record your tests through the browser, while using JMeter as a proxy.

Comment: Mmm, the problem with JMeter is that (from what I know) doesn't render the html nor process javascript code, both things I'd like to include in the test.

Comment: JMeter does not render, it just downloads the files (it is more about server performance than client performance).

Comment: JMeter also does not support JavaScript, but if you record the session with your Browser, JMeter can later download it in exactly that order (if that is all you need from JavaScript).

Comment: I see, still I'm looking for a test too only for the client layer, not the server, that's why I thought about selenium

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the activities performed by a user inside a web-browser using HP LoadRunner.
Once you record a script, all you need to do is to hit the Run button & all the activities you want the user to do would be done by the LR script.
Also if you plan to load/stress test your application, you can use the same script to do it.

Answer (score 0):

http://gatling.io written in Scala

http://locust.io written in Python

seem like possible options not already mentioned.